# map coordinates in R: ggswissmaps

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, coordinates

When using `ggswissmaps`, I get long / lat coordinate that do not match a format that I recognize.

```
library(ggswissmaps)
data("shp_df")
    
head(shp_df[["g1b15"]]$long)
```

[1] 679207 680062 679981 680365 680281 680479

```
head(shp_df[["g1b15"]]$lat)
```

[1] 245176 244294 244051 243411 241866 241584

What scale could this be? It is neither the long / lat I get from e.g. Google maps, degrees, nor UTM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the co-ordinates are given in metres (Northing, Easting), using the [Swiss CH1903 / LV03](https://epsg.io/21781) projection.

If you want to convert this to standard degrees latitude / longitude, you can do something like this:

```r
library(ggswissmaps)

data("shp_df")

sw_shp <- split(shp_df[["g1b15"]], shp_df[["g1b15"]]$id) |>
  lapply(function(x) list(as.matrix(subset(x, piece == 1)[1:2]))) |>
  sf::st_multipolygon() |>
  sf::st_sfc(crs = 21781) |>
  sf::st_transform(crs = 'WGS84')
```

This now gives you a simple features column which is easy to handle. For example, it can be plotted like this:

```r
plot(sw_shp, axes = TRUE)
```

[image]